# can't get simple multido to build. MikTex 2.9 TexStudio XeLatex

Tags: multido

My first try at using multido and stalled straight away! This is probably obvious but, unfortunately, not to me!

```
%\tex\texMaker\graphics\pstricks\try-multido.tex
% Mil TeX 2.9 TexStudio using XeLatex
% 
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{bm}         
\begin{document}
\multido{}{3}{\Tex }
\end{document}
```

Just get 3 lines of 
"Undefined control sequence. \multido{}{3}{\Tex }"

Do I have to install multido outside if Mik TeX? There is a multido.tex here:-

```
C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\multido\multido.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> \Tex 

l.6 \multido{}{3}{\Tex }
```

showing the undefined command is `\Tex` (should be `\TeX`)

Comment: Thank you. To try mitigate my stupidity I must mention this one-liner is a gross reduction from trying to get  Herbert Voss's multido to work in the \psLame example (pp 545) - from his excellent book on pstricks. Must be a typo on my part, somewhere. I shall now try and work back up the tree as it were! tvm